# Active Directory historical data

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to query historical data from Active Directory? Does it keep it?

Can I execute anything like this:

Get User's Direct Reports
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151686.aspx

to find out the list of the user’s direct reports for a day in the past?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Currently (`as of November the 6th 2013`) there is no such option/feature in the WAAD.

The feature that I expect to see in the future releases (and is totally my speculation and expectation) is related more to auditing logs (such as who did what and when), which might eventually help you.